# I need to run a script during first boot and want the CLI to open for possible input

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, scripts, startup

Edit: I need a bit more explaining here. This is a one time only run personalization script for the computers that I have set up that I would like to run only on the first boot. After tweaking the code a bit, all I need to do now is to have the user enter their password to continue, I have a script that saves files to a specific area only if the peripheral is installed, and if it doesn't find it I want user input to direct to the intended peripheral. I would like to see the process as it runs at this point just to monitor that the process works properly and then I can take the CLI code out and use a GUI like interface to get the password for sudo. At this point I am the only one using the script and I just want to make it a little easier on myself.

Which options do I need to use to run a script on startup that will open the CLI before executing the script? I see a lot of options to run scripts, but every time I do try to run a script at startup for first boot or even at boot up, the script runs but does not show the CLI. I need the terminal to open when the script executes because of possible text entry during the process, this text entry is not guaranteed and depends on a couple factors depending on the peripherals mounted. I need to ensure the CLI terminal opens at the execution of the script from whichever way it is started.

I have tried using @reboot within cron and it works but there is no CLI after it starts and it stops on the text entry and I can't enter the data. How do I make sure that the CLI opens at the start of the script when it runs on first boot from whichever way it's done?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Do you want the script to run as your user or as root? Do you want to run it before or after you login as your user? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499338/edit) and add these information. You may also want to add your script in the question. If you do, format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: This is an XY Question.  What, precisely are you trying to do with "possible text entry during the process"? Inserting a human into the boot process seems like a bad idea - they're unreliable.

Comment: Edited the OP to give a little more explanation

Comment: Please tel us more about your system. Do you boot to a GUI or not? Which Ubuntu is this?